# Camel Rest DSL with jetty component fails to populate CORS headers correctly

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

I am having a hard time figuring out how camel rest dsl populates the CORS response headers when using jetty component as container. I have set the cors headers as follows

```
camel.rest.cors-headers.Access-Control-Allow-Credentials=true
camel.rest.cors-headers.Access-Control-Max-Age=3600
camel.rest.cors-headers.Access-Control-Allow-Methods=GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS, CONNECT, PATCH
camel.rest.cors-headers.Access-Control-Allow-Headers=Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Language, Host, Referer, User-Agent, Authorization, x-omit
camel.rest.cors-headers.Access-Control-Allow-Origin=*.example.com,*.example1.com,*.example2.com
```

However it always returns the list of origins rather than the value passed in Origin header.

I have tried enabling the CORS on jetty component and writing a custom JettyHttpBinding however, camel rest is still somehow overriding the values. My expected result is if origin value is in list of allowed origins then it should return Access-Control-Allow-Origin header as origin value otherwise return an error/throw an exception. Is there a way to customize this? Any help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to do this after getting some idea from following question.
[Add CORSHandler to a camel-jetty component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51701680/add-corshandler-to-a-camel-jetty-component)

However, I had to extend HandlerWrapper class instead of AbstractHandler

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper;

import javax.servlet.DispatcherType;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

public class CORSHandler extends HandlerWrapper {

    
    @Override
    public void handle(String target, Request baseRequest, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if (baseRequest.getDispatcherType() == DispatcherType.REQUEST) {
        // Custom code for adding CORS headers - similar to org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter::handle;
        }

        if (this._handler != null) {
            this._handler.handle(target, baseRequest, request, response);
        }

    }

}
```